# Android: Best method for displaying table data

Tags: android

I want to do a RSS reader, which would display an image (left alignment, text running around it) a Title flowing next to it, and a description, also running around the image.
What is the best method to do this in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/) from Roman Guy fits you perfectly. Still, if it's your first try on Android I'd suggest to start by visiting http://developer.android.com and reading the introduction guides and tutorials.

Good luck!